# Сборка Angular проекта с помощью Gulp npm

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp, npm

Добрый день помогите разобраться, не могу нормально собрать проект.

Постоянно работаю с NodeJS а тут пришлось еще и поставить angular.

Собираю все через Gulp.

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(source())
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals: true
         }))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/'));
});
```

Source:

```
function returnSource(){
    var files = [
        './public/js/*.js',
        './public/js/controller/*.js',
        './public/js/router/*.js',
    ];
    return files;
}

module.exports.returnSource = returnSource;
```

Структура папки JS

```
JS 
  controller
    index.js
  router
  template
  view
  app.js
```

Структура файла app.js

```
require('angular');

var app = angular.module('photography', []);
```

Структура файла /controller/index.js

```
app.controller("index", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [""];
});
```

Angular установлен через npm

Получаю на выходе файл bundle.min.js

Выдает ошибку при загрузке страницы о том что Cannot find module (И это со стороны require)

Не понимаю почему. По моей логике если я сделал require('angular') то в файл app.js должен переместиться angular.js из папки node_modules, а в итоге там почему то еще и задействованы функции require?

Как это сделать правильно?

[image: Картинка с ошибкой]

Comment: попробуй не минифицировать и посмотреть на что действительно ругается

Answer (score 1):

Так. То что Вы билдите через gulp не значит, что JS потом поймет вашу функцию `require`

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

это уже сторона клиента (**НЕ NODE.JS**) и там ни о каких `require('angular')` знать не знают :)
Вам нужно будет angular подключать стандартно через

```
<script src="path/to/your/angular.js"></script>
```

а строчку с `require` удалить из .js

Удачного кодинга :)

Comment: Ну по сути gulp собирает проект и вытягивает Angular из папки нод модулей и вставляет в файл, и сам angular уже есть в файле bundle.min.js. Почему туда еще и require затягивается?

Я просто хочу чтоб у меня все было в одном файле и мой код и сама библеотека ангуляра. 

Я кончно могу сделать в gulp изменения и собирать файл с учетом того чтоб он лез в нод модули и оттуда брал. Но думал это реализуемо через require

Comment: Видимо какой-то модуль предполагает, что Вы с помощью метода `require` подключаете модуль requireJs. Потому Вам придется подключать еще и этот файл... но ИМХО лишняя нагрузка на страницу. angular и так отлично справляется с модульностью

Comment: Как то все странно)

Comment: собственно всё понятно. http://frontender.info/gulp-browserify-starter-faq/ 
browserify получается обёртывает в requireJS. Между прочим можно просто в один файл angular конкатить и не придется мучиться с requireJS. С ним я Вам не помощник :)

Comment: получается он ищет файл angular.js в вашей корневой папки рядом с app.js и со всеми остальными js тоже. Естественно он не может его найти, т.к. он вообще вне области статики лежит. в node_modules

Comment: Спасибо за советы я конечно так и думал просто скачать ангулар и собирать со всеми файлами через gulp но была мысль что через require будет проще просто написал require angular и все круто))

Comment: Спасибо) Сделал по простому просто положил ангуляр на уровне app.js